# How come wrong answers get upvoted?

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

I really do not understand Stack Overflow.

Some people just give away code answers **without any explanation** and nobody cares, and this is not my only issue.

**My major issue is, how come the wrong answer can be upvoted and when you flagged the answer nobody cares ?**

For example [image]

As you see it has a syntax issue and a lack of explanation.

Does everybody just come to this website, so others can do their homework for free?

Comment: Because voters are people? Not much we can do about it.

Comment: Why would you flag that?  Moderators aren't going to delete an answer because you said it has a syntax issue - that's what downvotes are for.  If you flag that, we will just decline your flag.  Someone might not realize that there is a syntax issue so they upvoted it.  We can't do anything about that, **you can by downvoting wrong answers!!**

Comment: An empty catch block? Now I *have* to find that answer and downvote it.

Comment: @bluefeet so why when I down vote? I lose point?!!!!

Comment: @KickButtowski Because that's how the system works.  Downvote answers, you lose a point.

Comment: @bluefeet really? even if you 10000000000 points?

Comment: @KickButtowski um, yes even if you have a lot of rep - downvote an answer - lose a point.

Comment: @bluefeet Nothing in this world make sense lol how about just giving the code answer away issue ? as you see no explanation in the post

Comment: You get the point back if the answer's bad enough to end up deleted, or it gets fixed and you undownvote it. In any event, once you have a lot of rep, losing a bit of it doesn't hurt.

Comment: BTW: Commenting is free, and might give the poster and those clueless upvoters a hint.

Comment: @KickButtowski Then comment to the user to expand on their answer, downvote and move along.  There is absolutely nothing a moderator is going to do about this.

Comment: @Deduplicator    I commented yesterday and the person started down voting my all questions and answers so no thank you

Comment: @Kick, there is a trend (that I think is increasing, though I may be wrong) with answerers posting as quickly as possible replies with preambles like "try this", then code, and no other explanation. You're of course free to downvote such answers if you feel they deserve it.

Comment: If that is the case (even though it's an assumption) there is a system in place to catch such events and reverse them @KickButtowski.

Comment: @KickButtowski: Does not matter, it will be auto-reversed within 24h. If it isn't, ask for help. (Though you might be wrong about it being a vendetta)

Comment: @KickButtowski How do you know that it was _that user_ who downvoted you?  Voting is anonymous, making an assumption that, just because you commented on their answer, they downvoted you is wrong.

Comment: @bluefeet the person felt guilty and told me

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi did you down vote it?

Comment: @KickButtowski Don't ask people that, vote is supposed to be anonymous!

Comment: @bluefeet ok so lets this awesome website get ruined and nobody will stop these kind of posts. Such a good idea :)

Comment: @KickButtowski You are missing the point, you can help clean the site by voting - even if that means downvoting and losing 1 rep.

Comment: just follow some rules that not even good or logical. Lets have adv that StacKOverFlow the place which do your homework for free

Comment: Remember, "*flags should **not** be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*".

Comment: @KickButtowski You're the one who was refusing to downvote the post.  If you aren't even willing to step up and deal with a bad answer yourself why are you complaining about the fact that other people aren't?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi did not this answer has technical inaccuracies?

Comment: @KickButtowski Apparently you didn't notice the "**not**" in that quote.

Comment: @Servy I never complain why I lose point I am just trying to see how I can stop these people. I have learned a lot so who cares how much point i have

Comment: Related on Meta Super User: [How to deal with an answer that is popular but wrong?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7764/how-to-deal-with-an-answer-that-is-popular-but-wrong)

Comment: It's called the "Fastest Gun in the West" problem. Be the first one to answer the question, even at the cost of quality, and your answer rises above other higher-quality answers.

Comment: I have no idea what language that answer is in, but to me, the syntax looks valid at a glance. Similarly, a moderator might think the same, it isn't feasible for them to moderate this kind of flag, so it should be declined. If you disagree with the answer, comment/down vote away. Tell *me*, another user, what I'm missing, and maybe I won't upvote. I wouldn't upvote anyway for empty catch block, and for lack of explanation, but you get the idea.

Comment: If you see that the post needs improvement/correction, use the edit button. Don't use it if you have something to add, that's what comments are for.

Comment: @Joe: The error is probably that it should be 'pushNumber' instead of 'pushNUmber'. At least that's my guess. If it's really just a small typo, I think it would also be perfectly fine to edit the answer to fix the problem.

Comment: @RetoKoradi exactly - at a glance I didn't actually notice that typo, because it is so minor.

Comment: `how come the wrong answer can be upvoted`. Thats like asking why a political candidate can be voted for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Some people just give away code answer without any explanation and nobody cares

**False**. Many people care. I, for one, downvote and comment when I see these. You are more than welcome to follow a similar approach. Yes, you lose one rep which you get back if it's deleted...no big deal. If the person edits with an explanation then removing the downvote would be appropriate and would get your sacred 1 rep back.

Doing so may also indicate to the author and others what is appropriate conduct for the site. Note that you may get some backlash from certain users (I do from time to time) but it shouldn't cause you to lose sleep.

**Does it help?**

Yes, many times I have downvoted a commented that an explanation would be much more helpful. More times than not, the person thanks me, leaves an explanation, and hopefully continues to post more helpful answers.

> My major issue is, how come the wrong answer can be upvoted and when you flagged the answer nobody cares ?

Just because you think/know it's wrong doesn't mean that someone else does. Just comment and/or downvote so the appropriate people can learn from it if they so wish. Bringing it up on meta and not doing anything with the actual post is not helping those involved or improving the site.

**Flagging**

As it's been said many times before, mods won't accept a flag because of an incorrect "answer". If it looks like an answer (albeit incorrect) don't flag as not an answer.

Mods are here to handle things that the regular community cannot take care of. Things like this, we are more than capable of taking care of on our own so mods do not need to be involved.

Comment: just wondering to know why I got down voted by -4?

Comment: Since I didn't downvote, I can't tell you. But I can guess because it comes off as a rant and/or that people don't think it's helpful.

Comment: oh k I just wanted to see how I can be helpful so thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @KickButtowski - on downvotes - check [meta-meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) :) downvotes here often mean disagreement rather than "your question is badly written". Also your question welcomes both types of downvotes due to tone like "... nobody cares". More neutral tone possibly could avoid portion of downvotes you are getting on your question.

Answer (score 7):

First, we can't know why that answer was upvoted - voting is anonymous. It is entirely possible, someone  voted not realizing that the answer contained a syntax issue.

Second, you flagged this for a moderator to *do something* to this.  Guess what, that's your job here.  We aren't going to delete an answer because you said it has a syntax issue.  You can comment to the user, telling them there is an issue.  You can downvote their post, etc.

Finally, this is a site that is in place to help people - homework or not.  If you don't like how people are answering or asking, then comment and try to help people understand that we want good questions/answers.

Comment: just wondering to know why I got down voted by -4?

Comment: @KickButtowski Voting on meta is different, you tagged this as a discussion and it's possible that people didn't agree with your perspective.

Comment: k sounds fine I was just curious but thank you so much for your valuable input and thank you so much for being patient :)

Comment: I agree we, as users, must take the responsibility to rate content by giving upvotes to correct answers (that solve OP issues) and downvotes to wrong answers (solutions that do not meet the OP requirements). However, what can we do if someone constantly deliberately downvotes your answers while at the same time upvoting others' answers in the same thread, even if they are clearly not answering the question? Note it is not a single occasion, but repeated behavior.